# Zsh completion caching policy explained

Tags: autocomplete, zsh, oh-my-zsh, bash-completion

I'm writting some zsh functions using the powerful completion feature. The computation of my completions take some times and I want to make use of the completion caching policy. From the zsh manual (https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html) I found this code snippet

```
example_caching_policy () {
    # rebuild if cache is more than a week old
    local -a oldp
    oldp=( "$1"(Nm+7) )
    (( $#oldp ))
}
```

I couldn't find any explanation on the `(Nm+7)` syntax, what does `Nm` means ? With try and error I could find out that for example `Nms+1` would change the cache policy to 1 second, while `Nmh+1` to 1 hour. But where can I find the general `(NmX+N)` construct explanation ?
Same what does exactly means the line `(( $#oldp ))` ?

Answer (score 1):

I can explain the `(Nm+7)`

`man zshexpn`, search for Glob Qualifiers

```
a[Mwhms][-|+]n
    files accessed exactly n days ago.  Files accessed within the last n days are selected using a negative
    value for n (-n).  Files accessed more than n days ago are selected by a positive n  value  (+n).   Op‐
    tional  unit  specifiers  `M',  `w',  `h', `m' or `s' (e.g. `ah5') cause the check to be performed with
    months (of 30 days), weeks, hours, minutes or seconds instead of days, respectively.  An  explicit  `d'
    for days is also allowed.

    Any  fractional  part of the difference between the access time and the current part in the appropriate
    units is ignored in the comparison.  For instance, `echo *(ah-5)' would echo files accessed within  the
    last  five  hours,  while  `echo  *(ah+5)'  would  echo files accessed at least six hours ago, as times
    strictly between five and six hours are treated as five hours.

m[Mwhms][-|+]n
    like the file access qualifier, except that it uses the file modification time.
```

`N` stands for `NULL_GLOB`, if zsh matches nothing, it will remove the pattern.
Without this `N` option, if it matches nothing it will print an error.

Example with 4 files

```
$ touch lal # = updates file modification date to now
$ ls
lal  lil  lol  tut

$ ls l*(m+7)
lil  lol 
# files older than 7 days starting with l

$ ls l*(m-7)
lal 
# files younger than 7 days starting with l

$ ls l*(m+200)
zsh: no match
# no files older than 200 days

$ ls l*(Nm+200)
lal  lil  lol  tut
# N = NULL_GLOB made disappear the non-matching pattern so it's just ls
```

Answer (score 0):

As for the `(( $#oldp ))`, the function is supposed to return 0 if the cache is ok, and 1 if it needs rebuilding.

The previous line `oldp=( "$1"(Nm+7) )` sets `oldp` to an array that will contain one item (the value of `$1`) if the file was modified more than seven days ago (the `m+7` qualifier), and zero items (the `N` qualifier) if not.

That means that the number of items in the array is the same as the status we want to return!  So, `((` starts an arithmetic context (see `zshmisc`(1), “Arithmetic evaluation”), the return value of which is the value of the expression inside, and the expression is the length of `oldp`, which is `$#oldp` (see `zshexpn`(1), “Parameter expansion”).